# A vector containing pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, reference

**SOLUTION** I had to write `#include "polynomial.h"`, and additionally, I had to pass `P` as a reference to `addPolynomial`.

I have a class called `Function` having as member variable `vector<functionSegment*> functionParts`.

`functionSegment` has two derived classes, being `Polynomial` and `Exponential`.

**EDIT** The function `addPolynomial` is a function declared as
`void Function::addPolynomial(Polynomial* P, ifstream& input)`

In `main`, I have the following:

```
Polynomial* P; //I made a constructor that takes no arguments  
mainFunction.addPolynomial(P, input); //All that changes is the thing P is pointing to: NOTHING ELSE is changed  
(mainFunction.functionParts).push_back(P); //This gives problems
```

**EDIT** After re-examining the `addPolynomial` function I realize that the second comment is not entirely true: `P` is indeed `new`-ed. Thus, I should either write `Polynomial* P = new Polynomial` in `main` and use a copy constructor, or pass `P` by reference. I chose to do the latter.

The error is:

```
no matching function for call to 'std::vector<functionSegment*>::push_back(Polynomial*&)'
candidates are:
void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = functionSegment*; _Alloc = std::allocator<functionSegment*>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = functionSegment*]|
no known conversion from argument 1 from 'Polynomial*' to 'functionSegment* const&'
```

So apparently, `push_back` wants a `functionSegment* const&`, but it recieves a `Polynomial*`. Since `Polynomial` is of type
`functionSegment`, the problem is that we need a `const*& Polynomial`. This makes sense, because it is more efficient. But what should I do next?
`P` is a pointer to a Polynomial object, so we need a reference to a pointer.

`(mainFunction.functionParts).push_back(&P)` did not work.

Comment: `Polynomial* P;` will **not** call your no-argument constructor.

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) please.

Comment: in your `addPolynomial`, are you doing new there? Your code is a bit difficult to follow without all the pieces of the puzzle.

Comment: Did you forget the `public` when inheriting `Polynomial` from `functionSegment`?

Comment: @Bathsheba, you are totally right. It indeed does not call any constructor.
@CyberSpock, yes I am doing `new` there.   I realize that I should pass the pointer as a reference.
@nwp, I did not forget to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `Polynomial* P;` needs to be `Polynomial* P = new Polynomial;` unless `addPolynomial` takes P as a `Polynomial *&` and assigns a `new`ed `Polynomial`.

Now for the question. You have either forgotten to publicly inherit from `functionSegment` or forgotten to include the header, and have forward declared the type.

Comment: Chances are that `addPolynomial` creates the `Polynomial` that `P` points to so the first sentence may not be correct. Even if it was I would advice against `Polynomial P = new Polynomial;` and instead write `Polynomial P;`.

Comment: @nwp, the `addPolynomial` method might create it, but the comment makes me doubt that, and as he has a vector of pointers, he needs something on the heap to add to it if he is adding multiple. I'll add a clarification to the first statement.

Comment: @Dominic McDonnel, I should indeed pass a reference. Secondly, I did **not** forget to publicly inherit from `functionSegment`, but I **did** forward declare the type (I have `#include "function.h"` in `main`, and this file has the forward declaration),  and after writing `#include "polynomial.h"` I no longer have the error!  
  
Can you tell me why this solves the problem? I do not write `Polynomial* P = new Polynomial`, so `main` does not need to know about the structure of `Polynomial`, but why does `push_back` accept my `Polynomial` only when the header is included?

Comment: @SebastiaanDraijer, without the definition the compiler doesn't know that `Polynomial` inherits from `functionSegment`. So it seems like completely unrelated types and it doesn't know how to convert. Once you include the header, the compiler sees that the pointer is directly convertable to a `functionSegment` pointer.